# webpack sass-loader not using tsconfig path

Tags: typescript, webpack, tsconfig, sass-loader

Sass-loader seem to not use path (alias) declared in the typescript configuration. So a simple @use or @import give a not found error.

**Webpack**

```
resolve: {
    plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin()],
```

**tsconfig**

```
"paths": {
    "Components/*": ["src/components/*"],
```

**The result**

```
SassError: SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
1 │ @use 'Components/UI/Grid';
```

Is it possible to import the tsconfig path in the sass-loader ?

Answer (score 1):

**This is mainly because the extensions option doesn't include '.scss' inside `TsconfigPathsPlugin`, and you are importing file without its extension.**

**Solution1:**

use full file name for example

```
@use 'Components/UI/Grid.scss';
```

**Solution2:**

add extension `.scss` to TsconfigPathsWebpackPlugin

```
plugins: [
  new TsconfigPathsWebpackPlugin({
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.vue', '.json', '.scss'],
  }),
],
```

try add `console.log` in `node_modules/tsconfig-paths/lib/try-path.js` `getPathsToTry` function could real help you debug.

```
function getPathsToTry(extensions, absolutePathMappings, requestedModule) {
    if (!absolutePathMappings || !requestedModule || requestedModule[0] === ".") {
        return undefined;
    }
    var pathsToTry = [];
    for (var _i = 0, absolutePathMappings_1 = absolutePathMappings; _i < absolutePathMappings_1.length; _i++) {
        var entry = absolutePathMappings_1[_i];
        var starMatch = entry.pattern === requestedModule
            ? ""
            : matchStar(entry.pattern, requestedModule);
        if (starMatch !== undefined) {
            var _loop_1 = function (physicalPathPattern) {
                var physicalPath = physicalPathPattern.replace("*", starMatch);
                pathsToTry.push({ type: "file", path: physicalPath });
                pathsToTry.push.apply(pathsToTry, extensions.map(function (e) { return ({ type: "extension", path: physicalPath + e }); }));
                pathsToTry.push({
                    type: "package",
                    path: path.join(physicalPath, "/package.json"),
                });
                var indexPath = path.join(physicalPath, "/index");
                pathsToTry.push.apply(pathsToTry, extensions.map(function (e) { return ({ type: "index", path: indexPath + e }); }));
            };
            for (var _a = 0, _b = entry.paths; _a < _b.length; _a++) {
                var physicalPathPattern = _b[_a];
                _loop_1(physicalPathPattern);
            }
        }
    }
    // log any paths that the loader would try
    console.log(requestedModule, ':', {pathsToTry});
    return pathsToTry.length === 0 ? undefined : pathsToTry;
}
```